# Jezzy ViewPager to display fragment in activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So here is the situation, i have a class that extends activity inside which, there is a [this ViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) which is designed to display a blank layout and change its color with each swipe..
What I'm trying to do here is to to display a fragment instead n change its content with swiping, how can i do that?

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        TextView text = new TextView(OfferActivity.this);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setTextSize(30);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setText("Page " + position);
        text.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
        int bg = Color.rgb((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64, 
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64,
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64);
        text.setBackgroundColor(bg);
        container.addView(text, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mJazzy.setObjectForPosition(text, position);
        return text;
    }
```